# How to fetch data from one to many relationship using Django queries

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

I'm new to Django and trying to get path details of one specific image from the **ProductImage** table using the **place** field in the table and display the image.Where `place == 'Main Product Img'`
Product and ProductImage has one to many relationship.

My database has two tables named
`Product(id, name, price,..)` and `ProductImage(id, productid, image, place)`
which contains three images('Main Product IMG', 'Sub Img 1', 'Sub Img 2')

Here is my **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    desc = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    PLACEHOLDER= (
        ('Main Product Image', 'Main Product Image'),
        ('Sub Img 1', 'Sub Img 1'),
        ('Sub Img 2', 'Sub Img 2'),
    )
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='image_set', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    place = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=PLACEHOLDER)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**views.py**

```
def menu(request):
    products = Product.objects
    images = ProductImage.objects

    context = {'products': products, 'images': images}
    return render(request, 'store/menu.html', context)
```

**Template**

```
{% for product in products.all %}

  <a href="#">

    <img src="{{ images.filter(product__id=product.id, place='Main Product Image')[0].image.url }}" class="img-fluid mt-3">

    {% if product.discount != 0 %}
      <span class="bonus">{{ product.discount }}% off</span>
    {% endif %}
  </a>
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),

]

# Media files

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('menu', views.menu, name='menu'),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I was able to write a query in the shell to do that

```
>>> images = ProductImage.objects
>>> images.filter(product__id='1', place='Main Product Image')[0].image
<ImageFieldFile: images/img3.jpg>
```

The rest of the operations are working correctly. I've been trying to solve this issue for many hours now but keep getting

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /menu
Could not parse the remainder: '(product__id=product.id, place='Main Product Image')[0].image.url'
from 'images.filter(product__id=product.id, place='Main Product Image')[0].image.url'
```

Any help that is appreciated.

Comment: You can not make method calls in a Django template, the parenthesis are *deliberately* not allowed to prevent people from writing *business* logic in the template.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so I have to create a separate file for queries?

Comment: no, that would make the software quality an order of magnitude worse.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, okay now I get that...Thank you very much ...Can you please recommend me some references for further studies :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not make method calls in a Django template, the parenthesis is *deliberately* not allowed to prevent people from writing *business* logic in the template.

You can define a method, for example in the `Product` model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    desc = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=0)

    @property
    def main_product_image(self):
        return self.image_set.filter(place='Main Product Image').first()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and then render this with:

```
<img src="{{ product.main_product_image.image.url }}"; class="img-fluid mt-3">
```

but this will result in an *N+1 problem*, if method calls with parameters were allowed, this would also result in an *N+1* problem.

You can make use of a [**`Prefetch`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) to load the main images in bulk instead:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

def menu(request):
    products = Product.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'image_set',
            ProductImage.objects.filter(place='Main Product Image'),
            to_attr='main_images'
        )
    )

    context = {'products': products}
    return render(request, 'store/menu.html', context)
```

then you can render this with:

```
{% for product in products %}
    <img src="{{ product.main_images.0.image.url }}" class="img-fluid mt-3">;
    …
{% endfor %}
```